# Generating a protocol string

Tags: python, string

I'd like to read combined information from of a bunch of variables.
I tried this here:

```
class MyStruct:
    first_byte = 0
    second_byte = 0
    combined = str(hex(first_byte)) + " " + str(hex(second_byte))

test = MyStruct() test.first_byte = 36 test.second_byte = 128

print("MyStruct: test first=%i second=%i comb=%s" %(test.first_byte, test.second_byte, test.combined))
```

And I get:

> > >
> >     MyStruct: test first=36 second=128 comb=0x0 0x0

But I was expecting:

> > >
> >     MyStruct: test first=36 second=128 comb=0x24 0x80

I see that the calculations of them combined are made just when it is declared. But I don't know how to calculate it again.

Why I am using this:
I'd like to create a protocol-string for LIN-signals over a [CARBERRY](http://www.carberry.it/)
Here you can find further information: [LIN-command](http://www.carberry.it/wiki/carberry:cmds:subsys:lintx)

I'd like to define each byte separately like this:

```
protokol.pid = 10
protokol.D0 = value_one
protokol.D1 = value_two
```

and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, simply put, the line `combined = str(hex(first_byte)) + " " + str(hex(second_byte))`
is evaluated when you create the class.
What you could do is the following:

```
class  MyStruct:
    def __init__(self, first_byte, second_byte):
        self.first_byte = first_byte
        self.second_byte = second_byte
        self.combined = hex(first_byte) + " " + hex(second_byte)


test = MyStruct(36, 128)
print("MyStruct: test first=%i second=%i comb=%s" %(test.first_byte, test.second_byte, test.combined))
```

I suggest you take a look at classes, methods and attributes before you go any further, you may pick up a few useful tools.

Further explanation:
By declaring first_byte and second_byte directly inside the class, you are creating static class variables, accessed by `MyStruct.first_byte` and `MyStruct.second_byte`. Here's an example to illustrate what I'm talking about:

```
>>> class A:
    tag = 10
    def set_tag(self, val):
        self.tag = val

>>> b = A()
>>> b.tag
10
>>> A.tag
10
>>> b.set_tag(5)
>>> b.tag
5
>>> A.tag
10
```

Comment: It works. I think i understood whats happening in this code. Thank you. :)